# How can I create custom badges in Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: support, feature-request, badges, badge-request, stack-overflow-enterprise

Is there a way to create custom badges if you're running Stack Overflow Enterprise?

If you want to have a bronze badge when someone has done 10 upvotes, for example.

Comment: I do not believe that custom/user-defined badges are supported by Stack Overflow Enterprise. That said, as a Stack Overflow Enterprise customer, you should have "your own customer success and community building representative" assigned to you. Have you checked with them? Providing you with this kind of support is their job. Meta Stack Overflow is the support platform for the public version of Stack Overflow. We cannot provide support for custom/on-premises Enterprise deployments.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input! I would have given your comment an upvote and answered tick :)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, though! That's why I didn't post it as an answer. Meta follows the same rules as the main site with regards to what counts as an answer.

Comment: I got back some information internally and they say it isn't possible. Paraphrasing: "Turns out I can’t create new badges in our own instance. Problem partly solved by being able to create custom awards. However, these need to be awarded on an individual basis and manually…not the same as badges that can be provided based on reputation (automatic trigger)". :( How can I then request this feature? :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [tag:support] questions about Stack Overflow Enterprise are outside of the scope of Meta Stack Overflow per precedent at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416722/3750257